# Oauth xframe option issue on canvas

Tags: oauth2, x-frame-options

When we do oauth flow on canvas , we following error in browser console.

> setup/secur/RemoteAccessAuthorizationPage.apexp?source=

If I click on the url it works fine. It should work seamlessly in same window ? What is issue and how to fix this.

> refused to display : in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to
>   'deny'.

Comment: Do you have salesforce iframed in your web page ?

Comment: No, we have connected app from where we are doing oauth via canvas

Comment: did you get resolution to this yet?